# How to handle orders that are not paid in full?

Tags: payment, invoice, order-status

I'd like to deduct items already paid and generate an invoice for the still outstanding sum.
Whats the proper way to do that?

thank in advance
Milan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the wording of your question it sounds like Magento's stock invoicing system will work--however I would suspect you're question isn't quite what you're really asking.

A Sales Order in Magento can have multiple invoices.  Each invoice represents payment received for specific items from the Order.  So an order with three items (it doesn't matter if they're the same sku, different skus, or a mix) can have up to three invoices--one per item.  If an invoice has been created for one item, and you'd like to invoice the remainder then you can create a second invoice with the remaining two items.

However, I wouldn't be surprised if you'd like to invoice by amount rather than by items.  Something like "when a customer pays $100 of a $150 order, invoice and release up to $100 worth of inventory".  This isn't supported, however there is at least one 3rd party extension that allows something like it--however the extension I'm thinking of proved to be fairly low quality and problematic in our install and we've opted to do without it.